# How to quickly find the maximum-average interval?

Tags: algorithm

From an integer array `A[N]`, I'd like to find an interval `[i,j]` that has a maximized average `(A[i] + A[i + 1] + .. + A[j]) / (j - i + 1)`.

The length of the interval `(j - i + 1)` should be more than `L`.`(L >= 1)`

What I thought was to calculate an average for every i ~ j, but it is too slow to do like this.(N is too big)

Is there an algorithm faster than `O(N^2)`? Or I'd like to know whether there exists a randomized method for that.

Comment: Can you please post a short example?

Comment: You need L >= 2, for L >= 1, you can just return [i,i] where i is the maximum index

Comment: @barak1412: I believe he means `L` is a parameter given to the algorithm dynamically.

Comment: I didn't understand it that way. He better give some example

Comment: An O(N) algorithm is reported by Goldwasser et al. in http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0207026. You can download a pdf of the paper. You can also find an O(N*logL) one here: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~kmchao/seq04spr/jcss.pdf

Comment: @barak1412 The length of the interval should be more than L. and L is more than 1. Therefore, if L is given as 3, then the interval can be longer than 3.

Comment: For an example, if 1 5 6 2 9 and L = 2 is given as an input, then [6 2 9] is the answer.

Comment: I think @Tudor gave me the answer...Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an `O(N*logC)` algorithm, where `C` is proportional to the maximum element value of the array. Comparing with some more complicated algorithms in recent papers, this algorithm is easier to understand, and can be implemented in a short time, and still fast enough in practical.

For simplicity, We assume there is at least one non-negative integers in the array.

The algorithm is based on binary search. At first, we can find that the final answer must be in the range `[0, max(A)]`, and we half this interval in each iteration, until it is small enough (10<sup>-6</sup> for example). In each iteration, assume the available interval is `[a,b]`, we need to check whether the maximum average is no less than `(a+b)/2`. If so, we get a smaller interval `[(a+b)/2, b]`, or else we get `[a, (a+b)/2]`.

Now the problem is: Given a number `K`, how to check that the final answer is at least `K`?

Assume the average is at least `K`, there exist some `i`, `j` such that `(A[i] + A[i+1] + ... + A[j]) / (j - i + 1) >= K`. We multiply both sides by `(j-i+1)`, and move the right side to left, and we get `(A[i] - K) + (A[i+1] - K) + ... + (A[j] - K) >= 0`.

So, let `B[i] = A[i] - K`, we only need to find an interval `[i, j]` (`j - i + 1 > L`) such that `B[i] + ... + B[j] >= 0`. Now the problem is: Given array `B` and length `L`, we are to find an interval of maximum sum whose length is more than `L`. If the maximum sum is `>= 0`, the original average number `K` is possible.

The second problem can be solved by linear scan. Let `sumB[0] = 0`, `sumB[i] = B[1] + B[2] + ... + B[i]`. For each index `i`, the max-sum interval which ended at `B[i]` is `sumB[i] - min(sumB[0], sumB[1], ..., sumB[i-L-1])`. When scanning the array with increasing `i`, we can maintain the `min(sumB[0], ..., sumB[i-L-1])` on the fly.

The time complexity of the sub-problem is `O(N)`. And we need `O(logC)` iterations, so the total complexity is `O(N*logC)`.

P.s. This kinds of "average problem" belongs to a family of problems called [fractional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_programming). The similar problems are minimum average-weighted spanning tree, minimum average-weighted cycle, etc.

P.s. again. The `O(logC)` is a loose bound. I think we can reduce it by some careful analysis.

Comment: +1 This does not sink in in the first reading, but you have actually explained it well. Also, reading the answer along with this link helped me : https://activities.tjhsst.edu/sct/lectures/1112/binary102111.pdf

Comment: Why is `sumB[0] = 0` ? I tried implementing the solution and I think sumB[0] should be assigned B[0]. Could you please clarify this ?