# Finding subarray with maximum sum/number of elements

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Input: An array of n positive and negative numbers and a number k.

Output: Subarray of at least k consecutive elements with maximum sum of elements divided by number of elements in the subarray.

O(n^2) algorithm is easy. Does anyone have a better algorithm for this?

Comment: This looks more like a highest average subarray problem.  Very similar.

Comment: Does the subarray have to be consecutive or are you looking for a subset?

Comment: This question has a trivial answer: just find the maximal element of the array. A one-element sub-array, containing this element is the maximum sum/size sub-array.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev Not true. Are you forgetting "negative" values?

Comment: @Wug do you have a link for "highest average subarray" problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12128221/1009831

Comment: @AK4749: "negative" values do not change this trivial solution. Anyway, the question has been corrected.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev that's for array of integers. Mine is array of real numbers.

Comment: OK, probably not a duplicate. Still that question is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use binary search.

For a searched value `x`, consider the array `b[i] = a[i] - x`. Now find the maximum sum subarray of length at least `k`.

This works because the average of a subarray of length `k` is `(a[p] + ... + a[p + k - 1]) / k`. So we have:

```
(a[p] + ... + a[p + k - 1]) / k >= avg
a[p] + ... + a[p + k - 1] >= avg * k
(a[p] - avg) + ... + (a[p + k - 1] - avg) >= 0
```

So, if you binary search for the average, by substracting it from each element, if you can find a positive-sum subarray (find the maximum one and check if it's positive) of length at least `k`, then `avg` is a valid answer: continue to search in `[avg, max_avg]` to see if you can find a better one. If not, reduce search to `[0, avg]`.

Comment: Makes sense. The runtime order becomes O(N)*log(range of numbers). It's still not clear for me when to stop the binary search.

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi - you can stop it when the interval you're searching in becomes small enough for your purposes. Try stopping it when it becomes smaller than `10^-3` for example. If it's not good enough, decrease the exponent.