# In R: Want to find all "subvectors" with a specific length (9) from a large vector (length 300) , such that the elements sum to a given value

Tags: r, sum, subset

I'd like to find a way to list all the subvectors from the vector of salaries below, with the requirement that their sum lies between 54,000 and 55,000. I've tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948258/given-an-input-array-find-all-subarrays-with-given-sum-k) method in C, but it takes way too long...I think because it finds the vectors before applying the limits (54,000 < sum(vector) < 55,000). Is there a way to improve on this, and preferably do it in R?

I've asked a friend about this, and he suggests developing a method to apply the sum limits as you go; because otherwise, the program would have to find (300 C 9) ~ 4.8 x 10^16 combinations.

Thanks!

Here's the list of salaries:

```
Salary
10800
9800
9600
9600
9500
9100
8800
8800
8700
8600
8600
8600
8600
8300
8200
8200
8100
8100
8100
8100
8000
7900
7600
7500
7500
7500
7400
7300
7300
7300
7200
7100
7100
7100
7000
6900
6900
6900
6800
6800
6800
6800
6700
6700
6600
6600
6600
6500
6500
6500
6500
6500
6400
6300
6300
6300
6200
6200
6100
6000
6000
6000
6000
5900
5900
5900
5800
5800
5800
5800
5800
5700
5700
5700
5600
5600
5600
5600
5600
5500
5500
5500
5400
5400
5400
5400
5400
5300
5200
5200
5200
5200
5200
5200
5200
5200
5200
5200
5100
5100
5100
5100
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
4900
4900
4800
4800
4800
4800
4800
4700
4700
4700
4700
4700
4700
4600
4600
4600
4500
4500
4500
4500
4500
4400
4400
4400
4400
4300
4300
4300
4300
4300
4300
4200
4200
4200
4200
4200
4200
4200
4100
4100
4100
4100
4100
4100
4000
4000
4000
4000
4000
4000
4000
4000
3900
3900
3900
3900
3900
3900
3900
3800
3800
3800
3800
3800
3800
3800
3800
3700
3700
3700
3700
3700
3700
3600
3600
3600
3600
3600
3600
3600
3600
3600
3600
3600
3600
3500
3500
3500
3500
3500
3500
3500
3500
3500
3500
3500
3500
3500
3500
3400
3400
3400
3400
3400
3400
3400
3400
3400
3400
3400
3400
3400
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3300
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3200
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3100
3000
3000
3000
3000
3000
3000
3000
3000
3000
3000
3000
3000
3000
3000
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "apply the sum limits as you go"? And can you clarify what you mean by "subvector" (i.e. must the elements of the subvector be a continuous subset of the original vector, simply any combination of elements, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a belated response, but it might still be useful to somebody.

The idea is to generate all possible subvectors. Since the length of the vector is 320, there is 1 subvector of length 320, 2 subvectors of length 319, 3 subvectors of length 318, ..., and 320 subvectors of length 1. (Note these subvectors are not necessarily unique.) The number of possible subvectors is therefore "only" 321*320/2 = 51360.

Given the above, and assuming `x <- c(10800, 9800, 9600, 9600, ..., 3000)`, the solution should be fairly self-explanatory:

```
# All possible start and end positions of subvectors
subvectors <- expand.grid(start=1:length(x), end=1:length(x))
# Of course, start must come before end
subvectors <- subvectors[subvectors$start <= subvectors$end, ]
# All possible subvectors
subvectors$values <- apply(subvectors, MARGIN=1, function(r) x[r[1]:r[2]])
# Subvector lengths (for convenience)
subvectors$length <- sapply(subvectors$values, length)
# Subvector sums
subvectors$sum <- sapply(subvectors$values, sum)
# All subvectors that satisfy the constraint
solutions <- subvectors[subvectors$sum >= 53000 & subvectors$sum <= 54000, ]
```

There are 65 solutions, with lengths ranging from 6 to 17.

Unlike the C solution mentioned above, this is more of a brute force method (O(n<sup>3</sup>)?), but it's simple enough and still takes just 1 second to run.