# Subinterval of length >= k in an array, with maximum average

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of n numbers, is there a fast (preferably O(n)) algorithm which finds a subinterval in the array of length at least k which has the maximum average value?  Note if k = 1 the problem is trivial (just find the largest element) but I'm interested in k > 1.  I have a feeling maybe it's only possible to get something like O(kn), but that would be ok too since it would be a huge improvement over O(n^2) when k << n.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you want a faster version of `String.subSequence()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["How to quickly find the maximum-average interval?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12128221/1009831).

Comment: Thanks, I can't use the accepted answer there because I don't have bounds on the array element values, but the comments pointed to a paper than gives an optimal O(n) solution.  Sorry for the duplicate, I was using "subinterval" in my search on SO and didn't find the previous post.